# Average non-null values

Tags: python

I have the following query:

```
>>> ItemMaster.objects.all()[:3].values_list('rt_rating', 'imdb_rating')
[(None, None), (None, Decimal('6.3')), (Decimal('7.6'), Decimal('7.4'))]
```

What would be the best way to get the average of the above non-null values? For the above it would be `(6.3 + 7.6 + 7.4) / 3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter your result with a list comprehension, then use `sum` and `len` to calculate the average :

```
>>> li=[(None, None), (None, Decimal('6.3')), (Decimal('7.6'), 
>>> nums=[j for tup in li for j in tup if j]
>>> av=sum(nums)/len(nums)
```

Comment: Cool, yeah doing the same with my answer below, using `itertools.chain` instead of a list comprehension, which I find a bit easier to understand.

Comment: @David542 Yep you can but since you need to filter the items while you are unpacking the tuples it'e better to use a list comprehension.

Comment: I see -- that makes sense, kill two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in `python3` using `filter`, `chain` and [statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```
from decimal import Decimal
from statistics import mean
from itertools import chain

l = [(None, None), (None, Decimal('6.3')), (Decimal('7.6'), Decimal('7.4'))]

print(mean(filter(None.__ne__,chain.from_iterable(l))))
7.1
```

`None.__ne__` would mean you keep `Decimal('0')` which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can user `itertools.chain` to get all the non-Null items and then `filter` to remove the Null items --

```
from itertools import chain

items = filter(None, list(chain(*ItemMaster.objects.all()[:3].values_list('rt_rating', 'imdb_rating'))))
==> [Decimal('6.3'), Decimal('7.6'), Decimal('7.4')]
sum(items)/len(items)
==> Decimal('7.1')
```